# Run eslint for a single rule

Tags: javascript, eslint

How do I run `eslint` for a single rule? I want to fix one at a time on a code base with many errors.

Something like: `eslint --rule no-def path/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`eslint --no-eslintrc --rule "no-undef: 2" path`

See [`--rule`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--rule) and [`--no-eslintrc`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--no-eslintrc).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use your eslintrc file to keep your configuration (parser, plugin settings, etc), you can use [eslint-nibble](https://github.com/IanVS/eslint-nibble) with the `--rule=no-undef` flag.  This will respect your normal configuration, but only show you errors from that rule.

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of eslint-nibble.